# AlertDialog using SimpleCursorAdapter does not display values

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, simplecursoradapter

Im using a SimpleCursorAdapter to fill the list inside an AlertDialog. The SimpleCursorAdapter uses the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 layout.

The dialog pops up. The list has correct amount of entries. But nothing is displayed. If I choose one entry, the selected entry ist highlighted and the text from my cursor is displayed.

The selection chooses the right entry.

Here is my code:

```
Intent dataIntent = new Intent();
dataIntent.setData(Ereignistypen.CONTENT_URI);
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(dataIntent.getData(), new String[] {
        Ereignistypen._ID, // 0
        Ereignistypen.NAME // 1
    }, null, null, Ereignistypen.ORDERBY);

SimpleCursorAdapter typAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor,
        new String[] { Ereignistypen.NAME }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle(R.string.ereignistyp);
builder.setAdapter(typAdapter, this);
AlertDialog typPicker = builder.create();
typPicker.show();
```

What do I wrong?

I checked [Android SimpleCursorAdapter results not displaying in AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433923/android-simplecursoradapter-results-not-displaying-in-alertdialog). But it was little helpfull to me.

EDIT:
If I switch to android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item the list is displayed in an ugly style. But the entries are visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is there but is not visible because of style.

I made my own layout with slightly different styles.
This is the original simple_list_item_1 out of sdk sources.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/text1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:paddingLeft="6dip"
   android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
/>
```

I extended to following:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/text1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
   android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverseDisableOnly"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:paddingLeft="6dip"
   android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
/>
```

Setting the textcolor explicit solved the problem.
I'm not shure which layout is used if I set the items with [AlertDialog.builder.setItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setItems%28java.lang.CharSequence%5B%5D,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such item as id.text1 in android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1.
But simple_list_item_2 has one.

[Here is the source code.](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ba05919a9489c686/d97892018e5da288)

Comment: Are you shure? There is text1 in simple_list_item_1. Look at your link.

Answer (score 1):

Both have the correct id, here the source code...

res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml

```
<TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:paddingLeft="6dip" 
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"/>
```

res/res/layout/simple_spinner_item.xml

```
<TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" 
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle" 
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I think that the problem it is related to style, probably the text is there but not visible. That is the only difference between the 2 TextView. I am pretty sure that if you write your own xml with the exact same TextView but with no style, the text is visible.

Comment: It is as you assumed. The text is there but not visible because of style. The text color used in textApperanceLarge is textColorPrimary. Look into my answer for solution working.